# Does a Deck Transformation Truly Shuffle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Given a covering map $p:E \rightarrow B$, suppose $U \subseteq B$ is such that $p^{-1}(U) = \bigsqcup_{j \in J} V_j$ where $p$ maps $V_j$ homeomorphically to $U$. Then we *want* to say that whenever $f$ is a deck transformation, $f$ maps each $V_j$ to some $V_k$ homeomorphically. However, I think I have a counterexample to this (explained below) and it seems necessary to pick a **specific** partition of $p^{-1}(U)$ into disjoint open sets that map homeomorphically to $U$. How does one find such a partition? More precisely,

1. Given any such $U$ evenly covered by $p$, does there exist a partition $p^{-1}(U) = \bigsqcup_{j \in J} V_j$ such that for all deck transformation $f$, $f(V_j)=V_k$ for some $k$?
2. (Weaker assertion) Given any $x \in B$, does there exist an evenly covered neighborhood $U \ni x$ such that there exists a partition $p^{-1}(U) = \bigsqcup_{j \in J} V_j$ such that for all deck transformation $f$, $f(V_j)=V_k$ for some $k$?

**Counterexample to the claim that deck transformation respects *any* partition**:

Consider $p: \mathbb R \rightarrow S^1$ given by $x \mapsto e^{2 \pi i x}$. Let $U = p((0, \frac14) \cup (\frac24, \frac34))$ and consider the partition $p^{-1}(U) = \bigsqcup_{j \in J} V_j$ where $$V_2 = (1,1+\frac14) \cup (2+\frac{2}4,2+\frac{3}4)$$
$$V_3 = (2,2+\frac14) \cup (1+\frac 24,1+\frac 34)$$
$$V_n = (n,n+\frac14) \cup (n+\frac24, n+\frac34) \text{ for }n \neq 2,3$$
Then since deck transformations are translations of $\mathbb R$, a translation of $V_2$ is not equal to any $V_k$.

Comment: The weaker assertion is definitely true (just take $U$ to be connected). As for the other question, it is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1035039/39599). I'm not sure it is exactly what you are looking for though.